# Как сделать пересыл сообщений от чат бота в другой канал в телеграмме?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Как сделать пересыл сообщений от чат бота в другой канал в телеграмме?
Есть телеграмм бот,который постоянно выкладывает информацию, необходимо эту информацию дублировать в другой канал.
Делаем на Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests

chatID = 'ИД чата'
ipTokken = ''  # Токен бота 
url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + ipTokken + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chatID + 
"&text=" + "Переменная с текстом"
request = requests.post(url)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]